# How to change the theme of folded code in Spyder?

Tags: python, spyder

Is there any configuration to change the gray highlighting when the function is minimize?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) It is not possible to change the way folded code is displayed in Spyder, sorry.